# Connect to Access database from matlab

Tags: matlab, ms-access

I was trying to connect to a Access database from matlab, by following the example given in matlab documentation

```
1 setdbprefs('DataReturnFormat','cellarray')
2 url = [['jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DSN='';DBQ='] dbpath];
3 con = database('','','','sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver', url);
4 sql = ['select * from ' table_name] ;
5 cursor = exec(con,sql);
6 cursor = fetch(cursor);
7 data.data = cursor.data;
```

I got the following error when I was requesting data from table A, at line 6, the error message was:

```
Error using cell
Size inputs must be integers.

Error in cursor/fetch (line 329)
                                    outCursor.Data =
                                    cell(rowLimit,
                                    numberOfColumns);
```

I tried fetch data from other tables in the same database, it went without problem. What might be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I still hadn't got to the bottom of this yet, but retrieving the data incrementally worked for me, by setting the preference:

```
setdbprefs('FetchInBatches', 'yes');
setdbprefs('FetchBatchSize', '2');
```

@Daniel's answer also works fine, but it is difficult to get the column headers that way (let me know if you know how, I tried using another sql query but if did not work for me)...

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the documentation. `fetch` must be called with two parameters, connection and query and it returns the result, not a cursor.

Comment: Well, that is not completely true, fetch can be called with one argument, a cursor resulting from executing a sql query.(http://www.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/fetch.html), but your method did solve my problem! Thanks, I am upvoting for now, if no one came up with answers to why my error occur in a couple of days, I will accept your answer. :)

Comment: There is something really strange in the documentation: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/database/ug/fetch.html http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/database/ug/database.fetch.html Sometimes I don't really understand the way the documentation is organised...